# How I can upgrade gnome to latest(Testing or Unstable release) on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, ppa

Now I'm using gnome shell version 3.14.3 on ubuntu 14.10 utopic.
How I can upgrade gnome-shell to 3.16 or 3.15 91(on ppa:ricotz/testing repository).
Currently I added following ppa repository

- ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
- ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
- ppa:ricotz/testing

I updated and also upgraded packages. (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)

Can anyone help me to how I can get latest gnome version of gnome. I can also use testing or unstable version.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `gnome-shell --version`

Comment: Thanks @A.B. It's `GNOME Shell 3.14.3`.

Comment: After some more research I found that version 3.16 is not release for ubuntu. It's available for Arch Linux.

Comment: For Utopic, there is no Gnome 3.15 and 3.16 in these PPAs.

Comment: @A.B. Yes, you are right. Version 3.16 is available for vivid. `gnome-shell 3.16.0-0ubuntu1~vivid1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently gnome-shell version 3.16 is not available for ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn). But It's available for ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) and ubuntu 15.04 was released on 23 April 2015.

So now you can upgrade to 15.04 by `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
And to upgrade gnome-shell to 3.16, add following ppa repository  and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

- ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
- ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
- ppa:ricotz/testing ([click here](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing) to check all packages in this repository)

To add repository run `sudo add-apt-repository [repository-to-add]`